# Where is 'dotnet restore' default nuget config located?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I've encountered problems trying to restore nuget packages from corporate AWS codeartifact - the error was `unable to load the service index for source`.

Obviously it was an authentication issue because `dotnet restore` command didn't use what was set in global nuget settings `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config`.

I thought that this file is the default file for `dotnet restore` command, but it uses something else, because the following commands yeild different numbers of sources:

- `cat ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config`
- `dotnet nuget list source`

After running `dotnet restore --configfile ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config` the problems resolved (so far).

Where are the default settings for `dotnet restore` on Linux machine?